# How to specify a LINEAR DebtRemediationFunction for a rule in SonarQube 5.3 from a plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, technical-debt

I am a newbie in SonarQube plugin development. I would like to create a rule where the technical dept remediation is given with a the following formula for each issue for that rule: **dept = constant_duration * effort** where **effort** is given and different for each issue, **constant_duration** is specified for the rule.

I managed to create the following RuleDefinition:

```
public class SodaRuleDefinition
implements RulesDefinition
{
    public static final String REPO_KEY = "soda";
    public static final String SODA_METHOD_COVERAGE_KEY = "soda-method-coverage";

    @Override
    public void define(Context context) {
        NewRepository repository = context.createRepository(REPO_KEY, Java.KEY);
        repository.setName("SoDA");
        repository.createRule(SODA_METHOD_COVERAGE_KEY)
                .setName("SoDA aggregated method coverage")
                .setMarkdownDescription("foo")
                .setDebtSubCharacteristic("UNIT_LEVEL")
                .setDebtRemediationFunction(
                    new DefaultDebtRemediationFunction(
                        DebtRemediationFunction.Type.LINEAR, "1h", null));
        repository.done();
    }
}
```

Then in a Sensor class, I created the issue like this:

```
public class SodaCoverageSensor
implements org.sonar.api.batch.Sensor{

// ...

    @Override
    public void analyse(Project project, SensorContext sc) {

    // ...

    sc.newIssue()
        .at(new DefaultIssueLocation()
            .on(new DefaultInputFile(project.getKey(), resource.getPath()))
            .message(String.format("Coverage (%f) is lower than %f.", entry.getValue(), limit)))
        .effortToFix(1.0)
        .forRule(ruleKey)
        .save();

    // ...

    }
```

Finally I register all my classes via an Plugin class and activate my rule on the GUI of SonarQube for *Sonar way* quality profile.

```
public class SonarQubePlugin
extends org.sonar.api.SonarPlugin{

    @Override
    public List getExtensions() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                SodaClassCoverageMetric.class,
                SodaCoverageSensor.class,
                SodaRuleDefinition.class
        );
    }    
}
```

Everything works fine, my code executed (I triple checked that), the rule and the issues are created as expected, no error during execution neither in log files. **Just the technical dept does not show up on the user interface!** I found other issues with the same `DebtRemediationFunction.Type.LINEAR` type, which are working just fine.

Any clue, help or recommendation about how to get over this are highly appreciate!

Comment: Can you execute http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search?rule_key=soda:soda-method-coverage and check that is contains fields "defaultDebtRemFnCoeff=LINEAR" and "defaultDebtRemFnCoeff=1h" ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Yes of course, the response do not contain those fields. I get the following output:
 "rules": [
    {
      "key": "soda:soda-method-coverage",
      "repo": "soda",
      "name": "SoDA aggregated method coverage",
      "createdAt": "2016-03-08T10:25:26+0100",
      "htmlDesc": "foo",
      "mdDesc": "foo",
      "severity": "MAJOR",
      "status": "READY",
      "isTemplate": false,
      "tags": [],
      "sysTags": [],
      "lang": "java",
      "langName": "Java",
      "params": [],
      "debtOverloaded": false
    }